# Find the specific function to satisfy the equation

Tags: real-analysis

$e^{-(\lambda + \mu)t} e^{\int_{t=0}^{\infty} s_1(t)dt} = \frac{s_{1}(t)}{1+\lambda t}$, with $\mu$ and $\lambda$ are constant.

Is it possible for me to find one $s_1(t)$ to satisfy the above equation? Any suggestions is good. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $C=\int_{0}^{\infty} s_1(t\,)dt$. Then the equation is equivalent to
$$
s_1(t)=e^C(1+\lambda\,t)\,e^{-(\lambda+\mu)t}.
$$
For $s_1$ to be integrable on $(0,\infty)$, we need $\lambda+\mu>0$. Integrating between $0$ and $\infty$ we get
$$
C=e^C\int_0^\infty(1+\lambda\,t)\,e^{-(\lambda+\mu)t}\,dt=\frac{2\, \lambda +\mu }{(\lambda +\mu )^2}\,e^C.
$$
There will be a solution $s_1$ whenever the above equation as a solution (in the unknown $C$.)

Comment: First, thanks a lot. But I am littele confused. Why $\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{C} = e^{C}$

Comment: Just integrate the equation. The integral of the left hand side is $C$. Take into acount that $C$ is a constant.

Comment: Could I ask you to look at another problem: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2961442/find-the-solution-of-second-order-differential-equation-with-variable-coefficien