# Find the solution of second order differential equation with variable coefficients

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$s_1^{'}(t) = -(\mu + \lambda) s_1(t) + \mu s_1^{2}(t) + \lambda s_{0}(t) $

with initial conditions $s_1(0) = 1$. $\lambda$ and $\mu$ are constant, and $s_{0}(t) = \frac{\mu + \lambda}{\mu + \lambda e^{(\mu+\lambda)t}}$

The differential equation is second order with variable coefficients.

Anyone can help me? I am stuch in the finding the solution of this differential equation.